# git sandbox for anyone to pull/push to?

Tags: git, sandbox

Is there a git repository out there on github or elsewhere that allows anyone read write access solely for the purpose of trying out git commands (aka git sandbox)?

One can easily set up their own repository, but a single-person repository does not allow for a fuller range of trying out commands, and a multiple-person repository usually means there are people who are trying to get serious work done and therefore a "sandbox" would not be appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by "a single-person repository does not allow for a fuller range of trying out commands?"  AFAIK, you're not limited in the commands you can use on a single-person repo.

Comment: I think he's referring to a single user environment being an insufficient test of git's branching / merging capabilities.

Comment: Haha, I was a bit eager there eh?! Didn't mean to put words in your mouth! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know. But it's free and easy to create a repo on GithHub. Why not just do so and play with that.

Comment: Agreed. If it's just a sandbox / test environment for git itself (rather than your project) that you want; then just create an open source (free) account at github and start playing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [octocat/Spoon-Knife repository on Github](https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife) for experimenting with git. See [Help: Fork a Repository](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/)